# How to Improve Inaccurate ROS Timer

Tags: timer, ros

I use a ROS timer in my progarm and plot the difference between the expected event time and the real event time as follows: `event.current_real - event.current_expected;`. However, I plot the data and find that the ROS Timer is NOT accurate AT ALL. In my program, the timer period is set to 0.002 second, but the largest error (0.01152 second) could be as large as more than 5.7 times of that. The plot is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIsVY.png).

I know from ROS wiki that ROS Timer does no intend to be accurate and is suject to the system load and other factors. So what I want to know is how to make it as accurate as possible? Is there any alternative method to substitute the ROS Timer?

I am using ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04. The source code is listed below:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
std::ofstream time_file;

void callback1(const ros::TimerEvent& event)
{
    ros::Duration error_dur = event.current_real - event.current_expected;
    time_file<<error_dur.toSec()<<endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    time_file.open("time_file.txt");
    time_file<<"error_dur"<<endl;
    ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Timer timer1 = n.createTimer(ros::Duration(0.002), callback1);

    ros::spin();
    if(!ros::ok())
        time_file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could consider refactoring and use ros::rate as mentioned in http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time#Sleeping_and_Rates ?

Comment: Is it better? But it said "Note: It is generally recommended to use Timers instead of Rate. See the Timers Tutorial for details."

Comment: Are you using wall time or simulated clock in your example?

Comment: @Tik0 I think it is wall time.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of run-time context, ROS time (Rates, Timers, etc.) is based on :

- wall clock time
  OR
- analysis of the `/clock`topic.

That allows the ROS::Time to be set based on simulation data when replaying a bag, for example.

The drawback is that this process may lack precision (especially at the beginning, until the first `/clock` message is received).

So if you rely on time data only for internal purpose (computing short durations, for example), you may decide to use system calls/libraries instead to gain precision, but you will need to check that it runs well during simulations.

Source : http://wiki.ros.org/Clock